# Non-existant subdirectory URLs display a blank white page instead of redirecting to homepage

Tags: url, 404

Currently, I have Strict URLs disabled in my global preferences so that if somebody tries to access a page that doesn't exist, it will just bring them to the homepage. However, this only works on pages that are in the root of the folder structure. For instance if I go to http://mysite.com/nonexistant it will reroute me to the homepage as it should, but if I go to http://mysite.com/about/nonexistant it presents a blank white page.

I tried enabling Strict URLs and specifying a 404 page(because this will be what I do eventually) and the same issue occurred. http://mysite.com/nonexistant shows me my 404 page, but http://mysite.com/about/nonexistant displays a blank white page.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an 'about' template group or template within the default group? What happens at http://mysite.com/abc/def ?

Comment: Yes, I have an "about" template group.

abc/def redirects me to the homepage. Thanks for the response!

Comment: So it appears that the 404 page will display as long as their isn't a template group in the URL. Does anyone know how I can make the 404 page display for all nonexistent pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://mysite.com/about/non-existent` will load the `http://mysite.com/about` template.

This is because EE looks at that second segment automatically for a number of things... if there isn't a template name there it will try to load an entry with that url_title into the /about template.

To stop this behavior, add this into the /about template:

```
{if segment_2 != ""}
    {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```

Comment: What happens if there are sometimes a segment_2? For example, http://mysite.com/about/non-existent will load the http://mysite.com/about template. the non-existent should return a 404. But, what if there is a template located at http://mysite.com/about/staff. Redirecting all of segment_2 to the 404 will block that content.